# Results from AJAX submit are not being displayed

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form where a user can type in a username and the ID corresponding to it will be displayed. I am using AJAX to submit the data and display the result (the ID) without refreshing the page.

I am not receiving any errors in the console, but no ID is being displayed after the form is submitted.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <input type="text" id="username">
    <input type="submit">
<form>

<div id="resulthere"></div> <!-- where the ID is supposed to be displayed -->
```

AJAX/JQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form#form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var username = $("#username").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "result.php",
            data: "username=" + username,
            success: $("#resulthere").html(event)
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP (results.php):

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['username'])) { // checks to make sure the username isn't empty
    $json = file_get_contents('http://example.com?username='.$_POST['username']); 
    $json2 = json_decode($json); 
    $id = $json2->ID; // gets the ID
    echo $id; // displays the ID
}
?>
```

Comment: `success: function(data) { $("#resulthere").html(data) }`

Answer (score 1):

This line of your input

```
<input type="text" id="username">
```

it would be better if it has a name,
The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
```

and do this in your jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var username = $("#username").val();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "result.php",
      data: { "username": username },
      success: function (result) {
        $("#resulthere").html(result)                   
      }
    });
  });
});
```

In code of ajax, you have,

```
data: "username=" + username
```

which violates the jquery syntax, what you did is concatenate the two string, "username" and value from input#username.

```
data : {
 'username':username
},
```

`'username'`, is an input name while `username` is the value from that input

while this one, `success: $("#resulthere").html(event)` also violate the syntax,

for further reading, you can refer to this documentation http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Could you explain why it's better to use this method rather than the current one please?

Comment: The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

Comment: I know, but what's wrong with how I've done it? Is this method more compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Just change

```
data: "username=" + username,
```

to

```
data: { "username" : username },
```